# Python program saying variable 'dateNumber' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def dateCalculationNorm(year):
    a = year%19
    b = year%4
    c = year%7
    d = (19*a + 24)%30
    e = (2*b + 4*c + 6*d + 5)%7
    dateNumber = 22 + d + e
    return dateNumber

def dateCalculationSpecial(year):
    a = year%19
    b = year%4
    c = year%7
    d = (19*a + 24)%30
    e = (2*b + 4*c + 6*d + 5)%7
    dateNumber = 15 + d + e
    return dateNumber

def dateOutput(year, date):
    print("The date of Easter in the year {0} is {1}.".format(year, date))

def main():
    print("Easter Date Calculator")
    print()
    year = eval(input("Enter the year: "))

    if year >= 1900 and year <= 2099:
        dateCalculationNorm(year)
        if dateNumber > 31:
            date = "April " + str(dateNumber - 31)
            dateOutput(year, date)
        else:
            date = "March " + str(dateNumber)
            dateOutput(year, date)
    elif year == 1954 or year == 1981 or year == 2049 or year == 2076:
        dateCalculationSpecial(year)
        if dateNumber > 31:
        date = "April " + str(dateNumber - 31)
        dateOutput(year, date)
        else:
            date = "March " + str(dateNumber)
            dateOutput(year, date)
    else:
    print("Sorry, but that year is not in the range of this program.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am having trouble getting main() to accept dateNumber in the line following
(if year >= 1900 and year <=2099) Python is saying that dateNumber is not defined. I tried making dateNumber global at the beginning of the program and that worked (albeit with a warning from Python), but I know that's the sloppy way to get this program working.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you fix the indentation?

Comment: Yep got it covered, thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate `dateNumber`.

```
if year >= 1900 and year <= 2099:
    dateNumber = dateCalculationNorm(year) # Instantiate here.
    if dateNumber > 31:
        date = "April " + str(dateNumber - 31)
        dateOutput(year, date)
    else:
        date = "March " + str(dateNumber)
        dateOutput(year, date)
```

As it stands, there's nothing like that inside your `main()` function. There's no need to set it to a global either.